# R: Time-series from Dates: difftime vs lubridate, acf and spectrum

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, spectrum, autocorrelation

I have a series of 181 datetimes that signify irregular occurring events.

I want to analyze these irregular dates, so I created a time-series as follows:

```
# Create a sequence of hourly timestamps for a year
start_time <- as.POSIXct("2019-05-01 00:00:00")
end_time <- as.POSIXct("2022-12-31 23:00:00")
time_seq <- seq(from = start_time, to = end_time, by = "min") 
# This corresponds to the highest resolution available. The final interest is in hours.

# Create a data frame with a column for the timestamps
df <- data.frame(datetime = time_seq)

# Add a column for the values, initialized to zero
df$value <- 0

# Add some values at specific dates
date_vals <- data.frame(date = mytime, value = myintensity)

# Loop through the rows of the data frame and add the values at the specified dates
for (i in 1:nrow(date_vals)) {
  date <- as.POSIXct(date_vals$date[i])
  value <- date_vals$value[i]
  df$value[df$datetime == date] <- value
}

# Convert the data frame to a time series
ts_data <- ts(df$value, start = c(1, 1), frequency = 60) 
# 60 per hour, corresponds to the minute-wise sampling n time_seq.
```

The analyses consists of the following:

1. the interval between the time points
2. the acf
3. the spectrum

**Ad #1.**

I have trouble accessing the interval data:

```
mydiffs <- difftime(mytime[-1], mytime[-length(mytime)])
```

mydiff stays empty... Another way to calculate it is using lubridate::interval:

```
mydiffs <- lubridate::interval(mytime[-1], mytime[-length(mytime)])*-1
```

This gives a "Formal Class Interval" (mydiffs) where I see Data under ..@ .Data, however, I don't find how to access them.

**Ad #2.**

The lag in the ACF is the sampling rate of the time-series, right? So 1 Lag in my ts_data is 1 minute.

```
# Calculate the autocorrelation function
acf_data <- acf(ts_data, lag.max = 14400, plot = TRUE) #60min*24h*100 days
```

However, I am not sure

- why the plot only displays lags up to 200?
- should I enter the Date into ACF rather than the zero-padded time-series?

**Ad #3.**

The spectrum is drawn over Frequency.

```
raw.spec <- spectrum(ts_data)
plot(raw.spec, log = "no", main = "Periodogram")
```

However, I am not sure what the Frequency is. The sampling rate of ts_data is 1 minute.
And the Spectrogram displays frequency from 0 to 30 (Bandwith 8.9e-06).

I am interested in a resolution of hours, as the events in the time-series are clustered grossly at 13 events within 3 days every 50 days or so...

```
dput(head(ExampleDF))
structure(list(Date = c("2019-05-26", "2019-05-27", "2019-09-19", 
"2019-09-20", "2019-12-25", "2019-12-25"), Time = c("11:11:00", 
"04:00:00", "07:00:00", "11:11:00", "04:00:00", "11:00:00"), 
    DateTime = c("2019-05-26 11:11:00", "2019-05-27 04:00:00", 
    "2019-09-19 07:00:00", "2019-09-20 11:11:00", "2019-12-25 04:00:00", 
    "2019-12-25 11:00:00"), TimeOnly = c("1905-06-21 11:11:00", 
    "1905-06-21 04:00:00", "1905-06-21 07:00:00", "1905-06-21 11:11:00", 
    "1905-06-21 04:00:00", "1905-06-21 11:00:00"), Intensity = c(5L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L), Comments = c("Feeling ill for days", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), SeriesComments = c("This section covers some ", 
    "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(lubridate)
library(viridis)

mydate <- as.Date(DF$DateTime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mytime <- lubridate::as_datetime(DF$DateTime)
myhours <- lubridate::hour(DF$DateTime)
myintensity <- as.numeric(DF$Intensity)
```

Comment: Should I rather cut the question into several for each problem? Thanks